# AddThis functionality in android application?

Tags: android

i want to share on facebook,tweet on twitter same like Add This functionality

any one guide me is it possible in android? 
if yes,
then please guide what is the procedure for all facebook ,twitter,linked in..etc..
and without installing ADD THIS application in phone. i mean programmatically.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i guess i have not used word iphone any where but phone and which means it would be android phone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use android default sharing tool.. if the user has configured gmail/fb/twitter.. than u will be able with the same too

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing URL");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.url.com");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reallly prefer to include a AddThis functionallity then check out the [AddThis For Android SDK](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381271-addthis-for-android-quickstart-guide#.T4AUttU-ZQI). It allows you to emmbed a button into your application which has the 'AddThis' functionallity. Keep in mind that this is different from the "AddThis App for Android" which allows you to share content from other apps using AddThis.

Comment: recently i tried integrating it .. but ran in issues.. even @addthis support doesnt seem that gud.. so finally sticking to basic sharing option on android

Comment: The AddThis SDK requires the following permissions in your manifest: INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.  I don't otherwise need those, so I'll probably try using an Intent to bring up an AddThis URL in the user's browser.